# Python string FIFO

Tags: python, string, buffer

Does Python have any data types for FIFO buffering of strings?  I created something (below) but suspect I'm reinventing the wheel.

```
class Buffer(list):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Buffer, self).__init__()

    def put(self, nlmsg):
        for c in nlmsg: self.append(c)

    def peek(self, number):
        return "".join( [self[i] for i in range(number)] )

    def get(self, number):
        return "".join( [self.pop(0) for i in range(number)] )
```

Usage example:

```
>>> buf = Buffer()
>>> buf.put('abcdefg')
>>> buf
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> buf.peek(4)
'abcd'
>>> buf
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> buf.get(5)
'abcde'
>>> buf
['f', 'g']
```

I looked at `Queue` but when adding a str I would have to split each byte manually, else the entire str would become an item in the queue.  Is there anything like this already out there?

Comment: Does StringIO do what you need? http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.StringIO

Comment: @ThomasK I hadn't looked at that. but at a glance it looks like it might not work since when reading off the front, it looks like i would have to shift the remaining data, or keep a pointer to where I'm reading in the string. (im kind of a newb, so i might be missing something)

Comment: A class wrapper is I good idea. I would inherit from `str` rather than list however. String already has slicing capabilities and it would save the cost of using `join`. `timeit` and see what works better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `collections.deque` it would be implemented as follows:

```
from collections import deque

class Buffer(deque):
    def put(self, iterable):
        for i in iterable:
            self.append(i)

    def peek(self, how_many):
        return ''.join([self[i] for i in xrange(how_many)])

    def get(self, how_many):
        return ''.join([self.popleft() for _ in xrange(how_many)])



buf = Buffer()
buf.put('abcdefg')
print buf
print buf.peek(4)
print buf
print buf.get(5)
print buf
```

Example output:

```
deque(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
abcd
deque(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
abcde
deque(['f', 'g'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is old, but the deque object supports already "string-buffering" if you are using joining:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> string_buffer = dequeue()
>>> string_buffer.append("a")
>>> string_buffer.append("b")
>>> "".join(string_buffer)
ab
```

No need to write a new class.

Answer (score 0):

How about the string type itself?

```
>>> buf = ""
>>> buf += "abcdefg"
>>> buf
'abcdefg'
>>> list(buf)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> buf[:4] # instead of peek
'abcd'
>>> got,buf = buf[:5],buf[5:] # instead of get
>>> got
'abcde'
>>> buf
'fg'
```

The idiom for get() is the only thing that's noticeably ugly here.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I thought I'd rather use a `list` since strings aren't mutable.

Comment: If you're going to use a list, check out `collecitons.deque` instead.